# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Jinja2'

Tags: python

'I have already installed jinja2 version
Jinja2==3.1.2
but still getting below error:

root@user-PC:/home/user/python# python
Python 3.11.0a7 (main, May 28 2023, 06:49:03) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import jinja2
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> > > File "/home/user/python/jinja2.py", line 2, in <module>
> > > import Jinja2
> > > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Jinja2'

I even lowered down the version but still getting the same error.
This is on ubuntu version 18 VM. And I installed jinja2 by pip3 mechanism.

Can someone please help me what am doing wrong here.

Tested with different python and jinja versions.'

Comment: It looks like you have named your own file `jinja2.py`, which prevents Python from finding the actual `jinja2` module. Name your file something else.